# How to disable routing in parent and child mapping for Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have explicitly disabled routing for my Elasticsearch(ES) mapping:

```
{
 "chow-clfg": {
  "_parent": {
   "type": "chow-demo"
  },
  "_routing": {
   "required": false
  },
  "_id": {
   "path": "clfg"
  },
  "dynamic": "true",
  "_ttl": {
   "enabled": true,
   "default": "1h"
  },
  "properties": {
   "clfg": {
    "analyzer": "keyword",
    "type": "string"
   },
   "@timestamp": {
    "format": "dateOptionalTime",
    "type": "date"
   },
   "count": {
    "type": "long"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

After doing curl command to delete and update the new mapping, I still get the routing enabled when I do a _cluster/state command:

```
"mappings" : {
 "chow-clfg" : {
  "_id" : {
   "path" : "clfg"
  },
  "_routing" : {
   "required" : true
  },
  "_ttl" : {
   "enabled" : true,
   "default" : 3600000
  },
  "properties" : {
   "@timestamp" : {
    "format" : "dateOptionalTime",
    "type" : "date"
   },
   "clfg" : {
    "analyzer" : "keyword",
    "type" : "string"
   },
   "count" : {
    "type" : "long"
   }
  },
  "_parent" : {
   "type" : "chow-demo"
  }
}
```

So it leaves me with the following questions:

1. How can I disable the routing if it is not a necessary requirement to have in a parent/child mapping?
2. If routing is a requirement, can routing be done on a field that is not unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Child documents have to be stored in the same shard as their parent documents. That's why routing for children documents is required. By default, documents are routed by their id values, therefore child documents are using parent's id for routing. You can change it. As long as parents and all their children are using the same routing value you should be fine. The routing field doesn't have to be unique but to achieve a good performance it should be more or less uniformly distributed. Otherwise, you might end up with a lot of records in one shard and only a few records in another.